# jQuery UI position widget bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

I'm having an issue when trying to position ajax loaded content with position 'fixed' in the center of the 'window' element in webkit browsers (Chrome/Safari). It works fine until you scroll down and try to load the content again.

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamiller619/RtVMP/1/). The first instance of 'Click me...' opens the modal fine in the center (vertical and horizontal) of the window element. However, scroll down and click the second instance and you see the modal is now below the viewport. However, it only happens with ajax loaded content. [Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamiller619/EMAG3/1/) that demonstrates it working with local content.

Ideas?

Thanks!